# C3861 Error (I really tried)

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli, identifier

I promise I searched high and low for the solution. You're my last resort.
I am getting the error

> Error 6   error C3861: 'saveSessionLurch': identifier not found   420 1   cs482newUI

Here is my code for XMLExport.h

```
#ifndef XMLEXPORT_H_
#define XMLEXPORT_H_

#include <vcclr.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

    class XMLExport{
    public:
        void saveSessionLurch();
        XMLExport();

    };//end class XMLExport

#endif
```

this is my code for XMLExport.cpp:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "XMLExport.h"

void XMLExport::saveSessionLurch(){

}//end SaveSessionLurch
```

this will eventually do something but I am just trying to get it to compile as of right now. 

and here is the code for Form1.h. I actually cut out most of the code that isnt relevant to this question.
this is the top of the code:

```
#pragma once
#include "Cell.h"
#include "Session.h"
#include "systemObjectWrapper.h"
#include "XMLExport.h"
```

and this is where the error occurs. The SaveFileDialog opens up so I know the click is working:

```
private: System::Void saveSessionButton_Click(System::Object^ sender,System::EventArgs^ e){
                      SaveFileDialog^ saveFileDialog1 = gcnew SaveFileDialog;
                      saveFileDialog1->ShowDialog()
                     saveSessionLurch();//THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS

               }
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help. It will be well rewarded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `saveSessionLurch` on an instance of the `XMLExport` class.

Comment: I'm embarassed... I don't know what that means. Can you expand upon that?

Comment: You need to learn basic object-oriented programming, about classes, methods, and instances.

Comment: I know all that. I just want to make sure I'm understanding you right. do you mean in form1.h create a new instance of the xmlExport then call saveSessionLurch from that instance? as in `this->XMLExport = new XMLExport(); this->XMLExport.saveSessionLurch();`

Comment: it doesnt work though. I edited XMLExport.h as ` public:
  XMLExport();
  void saveSessionLurch();` then I edited XMLExport.cpp as `XMLExport::XMLExport(){

}`

Comment: What error do you get?  You probably need to use `->` instead of `.`.

Comment: error C2039: 'XMLExport' : is not a member of 'cs482newUI::Form1' cs482newUI
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'XMLExport' 
error C2039: 'XMLExport' : is not a member of 'cs482newUI::Form1'
error C2227: left of '->saveSessionLurch' must point to class/struct/union/generic

Comment: and i just tried the -> (btw thank you for the help so far. its nice knowing I'm not going crazy alone)

Comment: You need to create a variable or field to put it in.

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhh so like: `XMLExport x = new XMLExport(); x->XMLExport->saveSessionLurch();`

Comment: **You need to learn how fields and objects work**.  Blundering around with various snippets without understanding what they mean will get you nowhere. ​ ​ ​ ​  (that's almost correct)

Comment: `XMLExport* x = new XMLExport(); x->saveSessionLurch();`

Comment: @Luron : That's probably **not** right; you *probably* need a data member on your `Form1` class rather than a local variable inside the event handler.